# How to store single quote to postgres in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

i have an error when i'am stored data from json response to postgresql. How to store data with a single quote in python?

my json response :

```
{
"status": 2,
"records": 1,
"message": "OK",
"id": "131",
"name": "SUPA'AT",
"address": "RUNGKUT SA'GIRI"
}
```

my python code :

```
sql = "UPDATE my_data SET name='"+str(response["name"])+"', address='"+str(response["address"])+"' WHERE id='"+id+"'"
cursor.execute(sql)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Before even going further. You need to stop creating your SQL queries like this. This is prime SQL injection material. You NEED to use parametrized queries. https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection

Comment: If you're using `psycopg` the `docs` cover your exact issue and how to correctly parametrize your queries. https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters

Comment: @PacketLoss thanks sir, i am newbie in python and will be to use parameterized queries

Comment: @NirAlfasi mean to replace single quote to double first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
sql = "UPDATE my_data SET name = %s, address = %s WHERE id = %s"
cursor.execute(sql, response["name"], response["address"], id)
conn.commit()
```

Assuming you assigned `id` somewhere previously.

The code you shared is a SQL code injection nightmare, as indicated by @PacketLoss in the comments and explained on https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection

Comment: You'll find that this is safer, easier to read and as a bonus, also solves you single quote problem, since `cursor.execute()` will appropriately escape it for you.